# How to clean up output of webpack dev build in docker?

Tags: docker, vue.js, webpack

This is more of an annoyance than anything, but when I run vue-cli under docker in development mode, I get a huge number of output lines. If I run the same thing NOT under docker, all of those lines write over each other. That is, under docker, I see in my output lots of lines like this:

```
node | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 34/59 modules 25 active /srv/app/node_modules/core-js/internals/an-instance.js
node | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 34/60 modules 26 active /srv/app/node_modules/core-js/internals/iterate.js
node | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 34/61 modules 27 active /srv/app/node_modules/core-js/internals/task.js
node | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 34/62 modules 28 active /srv/app/node_modules/core-js/internals/new-promise-capability.js
```

Is there a way to have it act the same was it does on my Mac where it does only a carriage return without the line feed?
My `Dockerfile` starts with:

```
FROM node
```

Also, it knows that it is running under Docker. At the end it says:

```
node |   It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
node |   Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/
```